# Fault code retention on scania

Tags: electronic-control-module, scania

I had an incident in a Scania which was showing an "ABS Malfunction" warning on the dash at the time.

My inquiry is if it is possible to "historically" look into the system and see the fault and any other info regarding the fault. Such as time first set.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Time set is unlikely, systems like abs tend to retain codes until cleared manually.

Comment: OBD-II codes usually do not have any "date stamping" that I'm aware of.  Modern ECUs have no clue what day or time it is.  I think this is changing with OBD-III, but that doesn't help you.